# Add spaces between characters in Assembly Language

Tags: assembly, arm

I am very new to ARM Assembly Language. I am supposed to write a program that takes a string input of 5 characters, and outputs that same string but with spaces between each character.  I have only figured out how to get input/output but not how to add the spaces.  My code is below, any help is much appreciated!

```
;-------------------------------------  ; DATA segment in RAM
    AREA    RAM, DATA, NOINIT, READWRITE, ALIGN=3
buf SPACE   11          ; input string buffer   
;-------------------------------------  ; CODE segment in flash (ROM)
    AREA    |.text|, CODE, READONLY
main    PROC                ; main user code
    bl  Terminal_setup      ; setup TeraTerm communication
loop
    ; read string demo
    ldr R0, =prompt1        ; pass prompt address
    bl  WriteString     ; print "Enter string: "
    ldr R0, =buf        ; pass buffer address
    movs    R1, #5          ; max accepted string length
    bl  ReadString      ; read string, R2 = string length
    
    ldr R0, =prompt3        ; pass prompt address
    bl  WriteString     ; print "You entered: "
    ldr R0, =buf
    bl  WriteString     ; control output of input string
    bl  NewLine         ; start new line
    
    b   loop            ; loop back     
    ENDP

prompt1 DCB "Enter string: ", 0
prompt3 DCB "You entered: ", 0
    ALIGN
    END
```

Comment: Start by writing it in a higher-level language like C++ (treating the string as an array of characters) to figure out the algorithm.  Then rewrite in assembly.

Comment: Decompose the problem into smaller piece parts.  For example, can you figure out how to print just one character, the first character, of the user input?

Comment: A single `vzip.8` instruction can interleave bytes of two 8-byte vectors; https://developer.arm.com/documentation/dui0473/k/dom1361289996005 .  So if you pad your buffer out to 8 bytes, you can just load into a NEON register.  Of course, if you don't know how to do this with a scalar loop, you should learn that first.  Compiler output from a C version should be a good example.

Comment: Maybe less fancy: can you print the string's characters one by one on the same line with a loop? If so, then you're 98% of the way there.